# T-SQL - Rearrange a list of values in table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (T_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), T_Desc NVARCHAR(10), PriorityOrder INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'Apple',1
UNION
SELECT 'LG',2
UNION
SELECT 'Microsoft',3
UNION
SELECT 'Samsung',4
UNION
SELECT 'Sony',5

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Output:

```
T_ID    T_Desc      PriorityOrder
1       Apple       1
2       LG          2
3       Microsoft   3
4       Samsung     4
5       Sony        5
```

Goal:
To rearrange the PriortyOrder if a T_Desc value (i.e. parameter #1) were to shift up/down one or more rows.
i.e. If LG shifted from PriortyOrder 2 to 5 (i.e. parameter #2), the new output would look like,

```
T_ID    T_Desc      PriorityOrder
1       Apple       1
2       LG          5
3       Microsoft   2
4       Samsung     3
5       Sony        4
```

In other words, everything below LG shifted up for "Priortyorder" field. Also, this should work if Sony were to move from PriorityOrder 5 to 1 (moving up in the order).

```
T_ID    T_Desc      PriorityOrder
1       Apple       2
2       LG          3
3       Microsoft   4
4       Samsung     5
5       Sony        1
```

I've seen examples of moving/shifting/re-sequencing order one row up/down but haven't been able to figure out shifting over multiple rows.

UPDATE: The list can vary in the amount of data.

Comment: so, no matter what, the order in `T_Desc` column should be preserved..correct?

Comment: Is PriorityOrder guarantied to have no gaps or overlaps?

Comment: Looks like you just need an "OriginalPriortyOrder" or "PrevPriortyOrder" column and sort by that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.
1) the order in T_Desc has to be preserved.
2) no overlaps based on grouping (T_Desc) but gaps should persist if originally present.
3) Based on the req, I can only have one field in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @srcID, @srcPri int, @dstPri int, @minPri int, @maxPri int, @delta

-- set @srcID and @dstPri as appropriate

Begin Transaction

Select @srcPri=PriorityOrder from #temp with (HOLDLOCK) where T_ID=@srcID

If @srcPri<@dstPri begin
  Select @minPri=@srcPri+1,
         @maxPri=@dstPri,
         @delta=-1
End else begin
  Select @minPri=@dstPri,
         @maxPri=@srcPri-1,
         @delta=1
End

Update #temp
Set PriorityOrder=PriorityOrder+@delta
Where PriorityOrder between @minPri and @maxPri

Update #temp
Set PriorityOrder=@dstPri
Where T_ID=@srcID

Commit Transaction
```

You need to provide the T_ID of the row that is to be moved/shifted in @srcID and the target PriorityOrder in @dstPri. If you run multiple instances of the above code concurrently, it is possible to get a deadlock if both instances need to update the same records